# How to create Django HttpResponse to show plain text file (when doing domain control validation for SSL)

Tags: django

I've purchased an SSL cert and have chosen to use domain control validation in order to conclude creation of the cert.  With domain validation, the cert provider provides a ".txt" file to be placed in the root folder of the domain.  Of course that simple operation doesn't work in Django.  I've placed the text file in the static folder and created a url to return the result like so:
        url(r'^filename.txt$', 'dcv_validation'),

and a corresponding view for the domain control validation:
    def dcv_validation(request):
        return ??????

I've made a number of attempts to return the file to the same url without success.  The closest I've come is doing:

```
def dcv_validation(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('static/filename.txt')
```

but of course that changes the url from:

www.domainname.com/filename.txt

to:

www.domainname.com/static/filename.txt

and because of this change to the url, the cert provider still won't validate control of the domain even though the contents of the file are displayed in the browser.  I'm sure there's some easy way in Django, so what do I do to return this file while keeping the url the same?  (The file has only two lines of content that the cert provider needs to see.)

Comment: `return HttpResponse(open('path/to/your/file.txt').read())`?

Comment: @Bjorn That doesn't work and seems similar to this, which I had tried before posting my question:  return FileResponse(open('myfile.png', 'rb'))   (see here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects)

Comment: @Bjorn CORRECTION  TO  MY  COMMENT  ABOVE.   Your answer works.  I had the path wrong when I first tried it.  Thank you!